# "Unable to display widget data" error

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I'm trying to add an iWidget to Communities, modified /local/con/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/config/cells/localhostCell01/LotusConnections-config/proxy-config.tpl and added a new proxy rule:

```
<proxy:policy url="http://questionmine.com/*" acf="none" basic-auth-support="true">
    <proxy:actions>
        <proxy:method>GET</proxy:method>
        <proxy:method>POST</proxy:method>
        <proxy:method>PUT</proxy:method>
        <proxy:method>DELETE</proxy:method>
    </proxy:actions>
    <proxy:headers>
        <proxy:header>User-Agent</proxy:header>
        <proxy:header>Accept.*</proxy:header>
        <proxy:header>Content.*</proxy:header>
        <proxy:header>Authorization.*</proxy:header>
        <proxy:header>If-.*</proxy:header>
        <proxy:header>Pragma</proxy:header>
        <proxy:header>Cache-Control</proxy:header>
        <proxy:header>X-Update-Nonce</proxy:header>
    </proxy:headers>
</proxy:policy>
```

But I still get this error:

```
Name: BMWIW0001E:Unable to load iWidget /communities/ajaxProxy/http/questionmine.com/app1/widgets/index/publishProject_iWidget.
Message: Unable to load /communities/ajaxProxy/http/questionmine.com/app1/widgets/index/publishProject_iWidget status:403
```

Am I modifying the right file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two profiles - AppSrv01 and Dmgr01.

If your Deployment Manager (Dmgr01) is active, and the AppSrv01 (Server Process) is up and running, it means that the master copy is in Dmgr01.

If you restart, the Dmgr01 copy overwrites the AppSrv01 Copy.

Think of it as Source-Copy relationship.

Try stopping the deployment manager and the appserver, edit the file in the Dmgr01 directory, and then start the Deployment Manager - Dmgr01
Then start the AppSrv01

A good link is
http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/connections/4.0/doc/en_us/ic4_p5.html#t_admin_config_ajax_proxy